# Oracle SELECT-Query does not return the expected row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

can somebody explain why this statement

```
select au.new_text, au.old_text
from bsaudt_cd_table au,
     bscore_sample_cont sc,
     bscore_sample sa 
where REGEXP_SUBSTR(au.visible_identification, '[^;]+') = TO_CHAR(sc.id) 
  and SUBSTR(au.visible_identification, INSTR(au.visible_identification, ';')+1) = TO_CHAR(sc.rno) 
  and sc.sample_id = sa.id 
  and au.record_id = sc.record_id 
  and au.table_name = 'BSCORE_SAMPLE_CONT'
  and au.column_name = 'DEPARTMENT_ID'
  and sa.id = 386608 and sc.id = 2207021 
  and au.old_text is null
```

is not returning the marked row in the screenshot below?

[image]

When I change the last line of the query in

```
and au.old_text is not null
```

lines #4 and #6 are returned...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: All conditions give the expected rows, right down to when I add the last condition.

Comment: `au.old_text is null` should return blue-marked row, while `au.old_text is not null` should return only 6th row. How did you check it? Are there uncommitted changes in another session which prevent you from seeing expected data?

Comment: @Littlefoot I`d expect exactly the same result. When I execute the query without the last line, the two lines #4 and #6 are returned. So ecerything seems okay until then. And no, there are no uncommited changes.

Comment: According to that, it seems that row #4 contains *something* in OLD_TEXT column. Otherwise, the 1st condition would return only that row, while the 2nd condition would return only row #6. What is result of `select dump(old_text) from that_table where ...` (use conditions that uniquely identify row #4).

Comment: ```select dump(old_text) from bsaudt_cd_table au, bscore_sample_cont sc, bscore_sample sa  
 where
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(au.visible_identification, '[^;]+') = TO_CHAR(sc.id) 
 and SUBSTR(au.visible_identification, INSTR(au.visible_identification, ';')+1) = TO_CHAR(sc.rno) 
 and sc.sample_id = sa.id 
 and au.record_id = sc.record_id 
 and au.table_name = 'BSCORE_SAMPLE_CONT'
 and au.column_name = 'DEPARTMENT_ID'
 and sa.id = 386608 and sc.id = 2207021```
returns 
```1 Typ=1 Len=6: 40,110,117,108,108,41
  2 Typ=1 Len=2: 53,51```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

This:

```
1 Typ=1 Len=6: 40,110,117,108,108,41
               ---------------------
               this
```

means that column contains

```
SQL> select chr(40), chr(110), chr(117), chr(108), chr(108), chr(41) from dual;

C C C C C C
- - - - - -
( n u l l )       --> this

SQL>
```

i.e. **literally** column contents is a string `'(null)'` (open bracket, letters "n", "u", "l", "l", closing bracket).

Run update and set it to `null`:

```
update that_table set
  old_text = null
  where <conditions that uniquely identify that row>
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! sa.id and sc.id can in fact vary, so an update on this column would not solve the general problem. But your hints led me to the solution, that I just have to query for  ```'(null)'``` and not for ```is null```